# No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"devise/books"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have added a search function to my application (books class) which already has devise and created a partial for the view:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'books', :action => 'search'), :method => 'get' do %>
 <label>Search</label>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
<% end %>
```

I also modified my routes.rb accordingly:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks =>  "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :users
  resources :reviews
  resources :books
  root :to => "books#index"

  match '/search', to: 'books#search', via: :get
```

Now when I hit the search button I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"devise/books"}
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1 <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'books', :action => 'search'), :method => 'get' do %>
```

Not sure why rails is looking for a controller called devise/books here. Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Slavko

Answer (score 0):

try

```
match 'search', to: 'books#search', via: :get
```

(No "/" in "/search")

Comment: This gave the same result.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
 <label>Search</label>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, :id => 'search_field' %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: This caused a SyntaxError in Devise::SessionsController#new on the first line.

Comment: Looks better. Need to push up to heroku to test. Thanks.

Comment: The search box now has {:id=>"search_field"} in by default :( and when I hit the search button I get an 500 application error - 'We're sorry but something went wrong'. Look at http://secret-brushlands-1375.herokuapp.com/. Logger debug output in books_controller does not appear to have been hit..